# ORA-01476: "divisor is equal to zero" in SQL percentage calculation

Tags: sql

I'm new in SQL, and want to set up an percentage calculation between MIN and MAX price by product (within 10 years). I keep getting error: ORA-01476:"divisor is equal to zero". In my understanding, the table gives me null values and I have to convert these?

```
SELECT
Price.Product,
Price.Curr,
Price.Price,
Price.Year,
((MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product))-(MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product)))/(MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product)) as "PercentageChange"
FROM Price
```

Expected results are number in price changes.

Comment: You are dividing by MIN(price). may be your minimum price is equal to zero and that's why the error. May be you can handle as "case if then else end" combination when MIN(price) equals zero and when it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your help Amit, this worked! Do you also know how to convert to percent?

Comment: Just convert the result to decimal if you want the result to be in percentage.

Comment: Percentage of what? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: When I run my code with CASE WHEN I get a column in number format. saying eighter 0 (if the MIN price is 0.) or example 0,1734449 etc. I would like to turn this into a percentage.

Comment: percentage compare to which value?

Comment: Percentage change between min and max value by product.

Comment: You can multiply the result by 100 and collect the result with column name as percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT
Price.Product,
Price.Curr,
Price.Price,
Price.Year, 
CASE 
    WHEN MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE (
             MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product)
             -
             MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product)
         )
         /
         (MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product)*1.0)
         *100.00 
END AS "PercentageChange"    
FROM Price
```

Comment: I think dividing it by Min price (original value is correct)?

Comment: This calculation will return MIN price is how many percentage less the MAX price. You can change any value as per requirement.

Comment: And Yes, if you use MIN, that will show Max is how many percentage more than MIN. Both calculation is acceptable :)

Answer (score 0):

use `nullif()`

```
SELECT
Price.Product,
Price.Curr,
Price.Price,
Price.Year,
((MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product))-(MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product)))/( nullif(MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product),0)) as "PercentageChange"
FROM Price
```

Comment: When doing this I get a message: ORA-00923: "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: Could you please clarify the meaning of the phrase "within 10 years"? You do not seem to address it anywhere in your SQL code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below. This answer is similar to mkRabbani. All I have done is change the  THEN expression (of IF clause). I have no way to test, whether it will work but looks ok.

```sql
SELECT Price.Product, Price.Curr, Price.Price, Price.Year, CASE WHEN MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product) = 0 THEN ( MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product) - MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product) ) ELSE ( MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product) - MIN(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product) ) / (MAX(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Price.Product)) *100.00 END AS "Change" FROM Price;
```

Please let me know the outcome (if it worked or not).

Answer (score 0):

Using common table expressions helps simplifying readability.
You can try the following:

```
WITH
Y AS (SELECT Product, MAX(Year) AS MaxYear FROM Price),
P AS (
  SELECT X.*, 
    MIN(X.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY X.Product) AS MinPrice,
    MAX(X.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY X.Product) AS MaxPrice
  FROM Price AS X JOIN Y ON X.Product = Y.Product
  WHERE (X.Year BETWEEN Y.MaxYear - 9 AND Y.MaxYear)
)
SELECT Product, Curr, Price, Year,
  100.0 * (CASE WHEN (MinPrice = 0) THEN NULL MaxPrice / MinPrice - 1 END) AS "PercentageChange"    
FROM P
```

If you need data for the latest 10 years regardless the availability of a price for a specific product, you can use:

```
WITH
P AS (
  SELECT X.*, 
    MIN(X.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY X.Product) AS MinPrice,
    MAX(X.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY X.Product) AS MaxPrice
  FROM Price AS X
  WHERE (X.Year > EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 10)
)
SELECT Product, Curr, Price, Year,
  100.0 * (CASE WHEN (MinPrice = 0) THEN NULL MaxPrice / MinPrice - 1 END) AS "PercentageChange"    
FROM P
```